# triangle with exclamation mark error symbol. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

since some days I got this error symbol concerning the update information. My sudo apt-get update is giving as follows.

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/rohityadav/vlmc/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

http://ppa.launchpad.net/rohityadav/vlmc/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you very much in advance for all your kind information.

Sincerely
Matteo

Answer (score 1):

Basically the errors are caused because the repo's you are trying to access no longer exist. You need to remove them from your list.

There are a few ways to do this .. if you have `Software & Updates` in 14.04 (sorry don't have that version installed atm so I'm not sure if it is installed) Launch the program and go to the `Other Software` tab and uncheck the two relating to `ppa.launchpad.net/rohityadav/vlmc`. This will remove those errors

If you want to do it manually you would need to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and if the ppa's exist in there you can delete them or put a `#` in front of the lines that contain them. If you don't see it in there then you can check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder and remove the ones in there that relate to the rohityadav ppa's.

Comment: Dear John, thank you very much for your very useful and complete anwer. I could fix the error without any problem thanks to your explanation.

Comment: if the answer helped you .. you can help me by clicking the checkmark next to my answer so I get some rep :D